# Prevent complex animation cache?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, animation

I have a complex animation where it will trigger when I mouseover and when mouseout the reverse animation will occur. But the problem is that when I try to hover over and out continuously the animation stuck.

*Below is my code with mouseenter and mouseout, just to give you and idea:*

```
$('body').on("mouseenter", '.template1 article', function(){

    $(this).addClass('nowAnimated');
    $(this).find('.articleHeadingWrapper').animate({height: "hide"}, 400, function() {

    $(this).parent().addClass('mainAnimatedClass');
    $(this).fadeIn(400, function() {
        $(this).find('.articleHiddenContent p').animate({opacity: "1"}, 400, function(){});
        console.log("hover in end")
    });


});     


});



$('body').on("mouseout", '.template1 article', function(){  

$(this).find('.articleHiddenContent p').animate({opacity: "0"}, 400, function(){

    $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(400, function(){

        $(this).parent().removeClass('mainAnimatedClass');
        $(this).parent().find('.articleHeadingWrapper').animate({height: "show"}, 400, function() {$(this).parent().removeClass('nowAnimated');});
        console.log("hover out end")
    });

});

});
```

Is there a better way of performing animation without cache? Thanks for the heads up in advance.

Update:
I have placed my code here instead:
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/deEFm

Comment: May you add a http://jsfiddle.net/ example?

Comment: try adding `.stop()` before `.animate()`

Comment: Hi is a bit messy, coz I just extracted it from the site,
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/deEFm, basically is the 5 pink/purple blocks, when you hover and out you can see the animation doesnt animate properly.....